# In Couchbase Java Query DSL, how do I filter for field-values that are not ASCII?

Tags: unicode, couchbase, sql++

Using Couchbase Java DSL, a query using  `"fish/piraña"`  gives a parse-error, but with  `"fish/piranha"`, there is no parse-error.

I had thought that the  `x()`  method would correctly wrap the non-ASCII Unicode string.

Using N1ql directly, this does work with any field name (except blank) or field value:

`parameterized("SELECT * from`" + bucket.name() + "`WHERE`" + fieldName + "`= $v", placeholders))`

How can this be done using the Java Query DSL?

```
    String species "fish/pira\u00f1a" ;
    Expression expForType = x("species").eq(x(species));
    OffsetPath statement = select("*").from(i(bucket.name())).where(expForType);
    N1qlQuery q = N1qlQuery.simple(statement);
    N1qlQueryResult result = bucket.query(q);
```

Comment: I got the same error. I will ask internally and come back to you tomorrow

Comment: This may have something to do with the need for escaping/quoting/parametrizing values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it works via N1QL:

```
   N1qlParams params = N1qlParams.build().consistency(ScanConsistency.REQUEST_PLUS).adhoc(true);
   ParameterizedN1qlQuery query = N1qlQuery.parameterized("Select * from `quicktask` where species = 'fish/pira\u00f1a' ", JsonObject.create(), params);
   System.out.println(quickProcessHistoryRepository.getCouchbaseOperations().getCouchbaseBucket().query(query));
```

I'm still trying to understand the behavior via SDK, I will update this answer as soon as I find the issue.

Comment: Another question is  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55338567 -- that one relates to ASCII identifiers, while this one is about non-ASCII Unicode.

Comment: Also, this question is about field values, while that question is about field names

Comment: thank you for looking into this. Please investigate how to handle not only field-values but also  field-names; and I'd like to use Placeholders for both values and names for the usual security reasons.

Comment: @deniswrosa
This seems to do it (Using BACKTICK since Stackoverflow interprets actual backticks as markup.)
select("*").from(i(bucket.name())).where(x(BACKTICK+fieldName+BACKTICK).eq(x("$value"))

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says it supports unicode.

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/literals.html

> Strings can be either Unicode characters or escaped characters.

Comment: That's exactly my question -- why does this not work?

Comment: Well, one of your questions is whether it supports non ascii 

Comment: That is the documentation, but in practice, it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Json strings can have unicode characters.

```
insert into default values ("f1",{"name":"fish/pira\u00f1a"});
select * from default where name = "fish/pira\u00f1a";
 "results": [
    {
        "default": {
            "name": "fish/piraña"
        }
    }
    ]
```

Collation (ORDER BY, indexing, ....) and data types comparison are based on byte comparison not based on unicode character. If unicode character is single/fixed byte it will work but if the data is variable multi-bytes may not work because comparison is based on byte comparison.

Comment: Ok, but then how do I query  for strings like  "piraña"?