# In Couchbase Java Query DSL, how do I filter for property-names that are not from the ASCII alphabet?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Couchbase queries should support any String for property-name in a filter ( `where` clause.)

But  the query below returns no values for any of the  `fieldNames` `"7", "a", "#", "&", "", "?"`. It does work for  values for  `fieldName` `a`.

Note that I'm using the Java DSL  API, not N1ql directly.

```
OffsetPath statement = select("*").from(i(bucket.name())).where(x(fieldName).eq(x("$t")));
JsonObject placeholderValues = JsonObject.create().put("t", fieldVal);
N1qlQuery q = N1qlQuery.parameterized(statement, placeholderValues);
N1qlQueryResult result = bucket.query(q);
```

But my  bucket *does have* each of these JsonObjects, including those with unusual property names,  as shown by an unfiltered query:

```
{"a":"a"}
{"#":"a"}
{"&":"a"}
{"":"a"}
{"?":"a"}
```

How do I escape property names or otherwise support these legal names in queries?

(This question relates to [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55323027/), but that is about values and this is about field names.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field name is treated as an identifier. So, back-ticks are needed to escape them thus:

```
select("*").from(i(bucket.name())).where(x("`" + fieldName + "`").eq(x("$value"))
```

with parameterization of `$value`, of course

Comment: My question is about property names, not identifiers. Also, the official documentation says that it can be any string.

Comment: My question is about filters, not about the projections that you are showing here.

Comment: Also, as mentioned I have no problem getting the values in the query results. Theproblem is defining a filter

Comment: same rules as identifiers applies JSON filed names. Same rules apply any where in query. SELECT * FROM default AS d WHERE d.`#` = "a";  If Java DSL API is not working you can use directly N1QL from java.

Comment: Your answer did lead me in the correct direction, though I still don't know the answer. Feel free to edit and I can upvote.

There is a bug in the  DSL API.

Using N1ql, this does work with any field name (except blank) or field value


parameterized("SELECT * from `" + bucket.name() + "` WHERE `" + fieldName + "` = $v", placeholderValues))

Comment: I don't about DSL API. Did u tried i(fieldName)  Checkout https://forums.couchbase.com/t/java-sdk-n1ql-not-data-return/9311/2

Comment: This does it select("*").from(i(bucket.name())).where(x(BACKTICK+fieldName+BACKTICK).eq(x("$value"))  , with parameterization.

Comment: If you need an identifier, this is what i() is made for ("i for identifier"). it will put the backtricks around your expression while a raw expression like x() does not.

In general, it is always helpful to take the statement and run toString() on it which will give you the raw generated N1QL and compare it to what you would've written by hand to discover any surprises early on.